# Installing Neo4j Community Server V4.0.1 on macOS

Tags: neo4j

Can I have two versions of the Neo4j Community Server database (V3.5 and V4.0.1) installed in macOS? I'd like to continue working with the V3.5 database for my current project, begin testing V4.0.1, migrate the current database to V4.0.1, and use V4.0.1 for my new project. Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a good strategy would be to use separate Docker containers.

If you want to use the same data set, you might try grabbing the Neo4j 3.5 container from Docker Hub and following the migration path (https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/upgrade/) to test out the actual migration and continue working with your data from 3.

You could also, of course, grab the Neo4j 4.0 container from Docker Hub and start playing around with new data if you just want to test out features.